# Handle different file open results in C

Tags: c, file, fopen

I hope to handle the following situations after trying to open a file in C:

1. file does not exist
2. file cannot be open - access denied
3. file name is actually a directory

For different situations, I need to print different messages.
Now I'm thinking using `fopen()` to do it. But I've never used that before. Is there any suggestion or link can help me?
Or if `fopen()` is not enough to return all the situation status, what function should I use?

Comment: Try reading the documentation, and including in your questions vital information like the platforms that your program is targeted to ... the answer depends on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `errno` global variable right after calling `fopen`.

`strerror(errno)`; to get specific error information as as string.

Comment: Should I do something like the following to print different error messages?
FILE *fp = fopen("filename","r"); 
if(!fp) {
    printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));}

Comment: @lkkeepmoving Yes, if you want to get the error messages. Or if you want to handle the error yourself, compare the errno to macros here <http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html>, and handle the corresponding error yourself.

Comment: I hope to print the error message to fprintf, like this: fprintf(stderr, "%s \n", errno); but errno is actually an int, right? How can I do that?

Comment: If you want a string, use `strerror(errno)`; if you want a number, use just `errno`.  If you want something else, you're going to need to create it.

Comment: @JimBalter What's your suggestion?

Comment: You can use the standard `perror()` function to print the error message to `stderr` - for example `perror("fopen")` will print a message like `fopen: File Not Found` to standard error.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to check the file attribute before openning the file:
you can use stat to archive that, see the detail, you can consult man page:

```
man 2 stat
```